# Completely Disable Firefox Cookies

Tags: firefox, cookies

I'm a web developer and I'm trying to test a web site with ALL cookies disabled using Firefox 24.6. From looking through the Tools...Options.....Privacy, I only see an option to "Tell sites that I do not want to be tracked" and I also found options about 3rd party cookies. In my specific case, I'm not concerned about 3rd party cookies. I'm trying to test if my webapp works correctly when it's first party cookies are rejected by a client browser.

Is there an option in about:config or some way to completely disable cookies in Firefox for testing purposes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Privacy tab in the options, select "Use custom settings for history" and uncheck "Accept cookies from sites".

Comment: that was what I was looking for.......I never thought to look for cookies under history.......superuser won't let me accept your answer for another 10 minutes though

Comment: @visitingFirefoxUsers8 The equivalent preference in `about:config` is called `network.cookie.cookieBehavior`; setting its value to `2` would disable all cookies. More info can be found here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.cookie.cookieBehavior

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) extension? 
From the Firebug console you can select the cookies tab.  Another menu will appear underneath the strip of tabs.  You should see "Default (Accept cookies)" and a down arrow.  Click that button to deny or allow _cookie and _session.